# ESP8266, configurado como cliente, no obtiene respuesta de una solicitud GET Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, http-post, http-get, esp8266

Un saludo a todos.
El motivo de mi post es solicitar ayuda sobre el siguiente Tema:

Tengo configurado un ESP8266 NodeMcu configurado como cliente con el objetivo de enviar un dato (Por metodo GET o POST) a una pagina WEB.

El problema radica en que, si conecto el ESP8266 a una pagina alojada localmente con Apache (Ejemplo: http://192.168.1.200/PruebaPHP.php?dato=Hola) o conecto con paginas de prueba tipo Json (http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/10) recibo la respuesta sin problema.

Pero cuando conecto con una pagina web que estoy desarrollando en Visual Studio con el motor ASP.net WebForm no obtengo respuesta alguna (https://192.168.1.200:44389/RecibirDatos.aspx?dato=Hola).

Si mando el GET  accediendo a la Pagina WEB mediante el navegador de mi Celular, mediante paginas WEB .PHP o desde el navegador del Televisor, obtengo sin ningún problema la respuesta programada en la Pagina WEB de ASP.NET.

¿Alguien tendrá alguna idea de porque la Pagina WEB ASP.NET no recibe el GET que manda el ESP8266 (pero sí el enviado por otros medios) siendo que el ESP8266 logra enviar el GET a otras paginas web?

Coloco codigo del ESP8266:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "INFINITUM4963_2.4";
const char* password = "HTDJTFt8e4";
String dt = "Hola Mundo";

int ledPin = 5; // GPIO5
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  //server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  int Uno=1;
  delay(3000);
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    HTTPClient http;
    //String datos_a_enviar = "dato=" + dt;
    http.begin("https://192.168.1.200:44389/RecibirDatos.aspx?dato=Hola");

    // Paginas con las que funciona el GET o POST
    //http.begin("http://192.168.1.200/PruebaPHP.php");
    //http.begin("http://192.168.1.200/PR2.php?dato=HolaAldo");

    //Eh agregado y quitado el .addHeader sin resultado alguno
    //http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    //http.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    int codigo_respuesta = http.GET();

    //Eh enviado por POST y tampoco funciona
    //int codigo_respuesta = http.POST(datos_a_enviar);

    String cuerporespuesta = http.getString();
    Serial.println(cuerporespuesta);
    if(codigo_respuesta>0){
      Serial.println("Codigo HTTP -> " + String(codigo_respuesta));

    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Error en la Conexion WIFI");
      Serial.print("");
    }
    http.end();

    //if (Uno==1){
    //  return;      
    //}

  }
```

Codigo del ASP.NET WEB form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class RecibirDatos : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string recibido = Request["dato"];
                Response.Write(recibido);
                Response.Write("Ok");
    }
}
```

En base a lo obervado en el Monitor Serial, no recibe ningún dato (ni siquiera código de error al almandar el GET)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Capturas de URL que ingreso en el Celular y la respuesta que obtengo cuando me conecto por el celular a la pagina web de ASP.NET:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura de pantalla de cuando esl ESP8266 se conecta a una pagina alojada en localhost de mi pc:

```
http.begin("http://192.168.1.200/PruebaPHP.php?dato=HolAMundo");
```

```
<?php

$dato = $_GET['dato'];
echo "Se Recibo ".$dato;

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitan mas información (código o evidencia) haganmelo saber.

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

¿es posible que puedas compartir tu código completo por otro medio? Por lo pronto, se me ocurre que puedan ser 3 cosas. Deberías usar CORS en tu aplicación permitiendo todas las solicitudes sobre cualquier sitio. Como segundo punto, puede que sea un tema de firewall o de tu modem, si bien ya lo probaste con otros dispositivos no asegura que sea efectiva en tu aplicación. También puede ser que no tu programa no está entendiendo la solicitud.